# Analyze data of One Column Dataframe based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with ten columns and more than a 1000 rows of data. I am cycling through each of the headers and calculating the difference between two headers. This results in a dataframe that is one column and N rows. I would like to then run statistics based on certain criteria. like give me statistics for a group of data that is greater than zero.
so the sample is something like this.

```
TempDF = df[Header] - df[SecondHeader]
    if (TempDF.median()>TempDF.mean()):
        print (df(TempDF[]>0).describe())
```

This generates a `Key Error : True` and doesnt show me anything.. please help.. I am trying to generate statistics on the resultant dataframe based on certain criteria.

I want to know how to accomplish that. Thank you.

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not filtering your Series object correctly. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame([[1111,22,33],[140,25,36],[47,58,69]])
df.columns=['Header','SecondHeader','ThirdHeader']

TempDF = df['Header'] - df['SecondHeader']

if TempDF.median() < TempDF.mean():
    print TempDF[TempDF>0].describe()
```